# SARS-CoV-2 virus floating in the air in *aerosols* for up to 3 hours

Tags: particle-physics, air

Good evening/morning.

I have a question related to SARS-CoV-2 virus spreaded in the air.

This [Straits Time article](https://www.straitstimes.com/world/united-states/coronavirus-covid-19-bug-can-persist-in-air-for-hours-and-on-surfaces-for-days) from March 18 describes a new study:

> The tests show that when the virus is carried by the droplets released when someone coughs or sneezes, it remains viable, or able to still infect people, in aerosols for at least three hours.

Examples of aerosol are fog, dust, particulate air pollutants (e.g. pollen), smoke, etc.

That being said, is essentially saying that the SARS-CoV-2 virus is *all over* in the air, right?

I am saying that SARS-CoV-2 virus can be *everywhere* in the world. Why? Because, for example, dust is everywhere in the air and air is not static, i.e. "it flies" from one site to another and hence it can move to a place where no infected people have been at.

Am I understanding this correctly?

Also, How far can the air with the virus fly? And how much of time it takes?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I have asked this question on chemistry.se (https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/129509/sars-cov-2-virus-floating-in-the-air-in-aerosols-for-up-to-3-hours) and I was told that would fit better on this site. I have just noticed that someone posted an answer on chemistry.se

Comment: I don't think this is a physics question at all. My lay understanding is that the aerosols in question are in particular suspensions of respiratory droplets carrying the virus, not arbitrary suspensions of pollen or dust. You should consult medical or virological resources.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't see how it's about physics. (I'm also not entirely clear on what the conceptual question here is. Perhaps, if there is a physics question in there somewhere, a clarifying edit could bring the post in shape for this site.)

Comment: @d_b In the future if you find yourself with that kind of impression about a question, casting a flag to make it official would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Because, for example, dust is everywhere in the air and air is not static,", generic dust yes, specific dust **no** . For example, when the wind in Greece has passed over the Sahara desert, we get an influx of red dust, and if it rains, the rain is red. This happens a few times a year. To have COVID19 dust, there should be an infection center, a person coughing and it would be in a limited area for a limited time , because the drops will evaporate anyway, particularly if there is a wind.

Comment: @annav Under what conditions could Covid-19 be there for up to 3 hours? I also watched a YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Uugj-zxA5E) 1:50 minute where it basically says that can stay over a particle and stay there for up to 3 hours.

Comment: One shlould search  see  https://www.aljazeera.com/indepth/features/doctor-note-coronavirus-spread-air-200324075120328.html

Comment: @annav oh ok, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a physics question, but it is still worth answering.

I asked a similar question elsewhere, This is the answer I got.

> At our hospital, the infection control guidelines are ‘droplet
>   control’, same as the flu
>   - not super high guidelines like for measles.
>
> The CDC guidelines are that
>
> You need to sanitize ‘high touch’ surfaces such as your telephone, the
>   cart handle at the supermarket, doorknobs.
>
> Things like packages and apples are deemed pretty safe – if you let it
>   sit for a few hours especially.
>
> The best estimates are that someone with coronavirus has to have shed
>   droplets on the surface fairly recently for it to be pretty
>   infectious.
>
> They estimate the rate of transmission from causal contact is 1 in 200
>   contacts- not exactly sure what that means.
>
> So I think going to the store is the big risk- you may touch a ‘high
>   touch’ surface that has seen many hands.
>
> Handling the produce  you bring home is low risk- only a few people
>   will have touched an apple, possibly many hours ago.
>
> Most transmission is from close contact- within households.
>
> We are washing hands and sanitizing many times per day!!
>
> Hope that is helpful.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I don't quite get how does this answer my question though

Comment: You were saying the virus could fly everywhere. The CDC guidelines indicate that droplets aren't everywhere. They are primarily on surfaces that get touched a lot. So not directly an answer of how far they fly. But pertinent.

Comment: But the investigation that I mentioned on the link says that the virus can float on the air over particles, for up to 3 hours

Comment: You do not seem to be really quoting the CDC here, you are *interpreting* what they said.  If you're going to answer it's better to quote exactly what they said using distinct formatting and make clear what bits are your own interpretation.

Comment: @StephenG - I was quoting a personal e-mail I got.